# I having compatibilty issues of WordPress theme with woo-commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I just updated WordPress and all the plugin.
Seems that the theme I was using is not compatible with the latest version of woo commerce, and I just need to fix the issue. Any idea or alternative to solve this bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );`

Write above statement in `functions.php`